# Using navigation rules inside a jsf bean

Tags: jsf-2

I've created a bean to search an sql table. This bean produces an arraylist that is displayed in a rich:dateTable. For each row in this table, there is a column that is a link to another page that specifies which record in the table is to be displayed, e.g.:

```
<h:link id="profile_last_name" value="#{record.string}" outcome="#{search.action()}">
     <f:param name="user_id" value="#{record.getInteger('user_id')}"/>
</h:link>
```

The search bean is passed a navigation outcome, e.g. "staffEditUser" that creates a URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/staff/edit/user.xhtml?user_id=98
```

I'd like to change the search bean so that if there is only one row in the search result, it immediately goes to the edit page. I know how to do the redirect if I knew the destination page name but I don't; all that I know inside the search bean is the navigation outcome. Is there some way to access the navigation rules from inside the bean?

Alternatively, and this seems very kludgy to me, could I simply add parameters to a redirect in the xhtml file that would be processed by the jsf navigation? If so, how?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the JSF page from within your managed bean method with

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("url");
```

As I understand you. You should check inside your ManagedBean database read method if the returned results have the size of none and then redirect to the edit page of this record.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear but my problem is that I don't know what the url is. All I know is what the outcome, which is a navigation case, is. What I want to do is find the url that the navigation case maps to. Alternatively, I could hack the xhtml by rendering and not rendering panels if I could get redirect code that goes thru the navigation model. Philosophically and esthetically that is wrong and ugly but if it works ...